# NFA to accept the following language

Tags: numbers, automata, finite-automata, dfa, nfa

I need to build an NFA (or DFA) to recognize the following language:
`L = {w | w mod 3 = 1}`.
So the way I tried it was to make an NFA to recognize numbers divisible by 3 and then just add 1 to them, but this approach is a lot harder than it seems (if not impossible ?).
I only managed to do an NFA to recognize numbers divisible by 3.

Comment: Any modulus-based DFA is going to have one state for every possible remainder, and an additional starting state. So in mod 3, you should have 4 states: `{start, q0, q1, q2}`. Each state will have a transition for each digit in the alphabet. Let's assume yours is base 10. To get you started, assume you're in the starting state. When you read a `0`, the remainder is `0`, so go from `start` to `q0` on `0`. On `1`, go to `q1`. On `3`, go to `q0`. On 4, go to `q1`, etc. The transitions from `q0` will be the same as `start`. I leave it to you to determine the transitions from `q1` and `q2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that w is to be interpreted as the decimal representation (without leading zeroes) of a nonnegative integer.

Given this, we can use Myhill-Nerode to iteratively determine the states we need:

1. the empty string can be followed by any string in L to get to a string in L. We'll call the equivalence class for this [e]. Note that this equivalence class corresponds to the initial state of a minimal DFA for L (if one exists). Note also that the initial state is not accepting since the empty string is not a valid decimal representation of a nonnegative integer.
2. the string 0 cannot be followed by anything to get a string in L; it leads to a dead state corresponding to equivalence class [0].
3. strings 1, 4 and 7 are in L so they must correspond to a new state. We'll call the equivalence class for these [1].
4. strings 2, 5 and 8 are not in L; however, not all strings in L lead them to strings in L. These must correspond to a new equivalence class we'll call [2].
5. strings 3, 6 and 9 are not in L; but these can be followed by anything in L to get a string in L. This is the same as the empty string, so we don't need a new equivalence class or state: the equivalence class is [e].
6. it can be verified that every two-digit decimal string is indistinguishable from some one-digit decimal string above. so, no new equivalence classes or states are needed.

To determine the transitions, simply append the transition symbol to the equivalence class's representative element and see what equivalence class the resulting string belongs to: that will be where the transition terminates. For instance, there is a transition from [e] to [0] on 0, from [e] to [1] on 1, etc.

Because 10 = 1 (mod 3), adding a new digit to the end of a decimal string will cause the new value modulo 3 to be the sum of the original number's value modulo 3 with the value of the new digit modulo 3:

```
x = a (mod 3)
y = b (mod 3)
x * 10 = x * 1 (mod 3) since 10 = 1 (mod 3)
x . y = x * 10 + y = x * 1 + y = x + y (mod 3)
```

Filling in the transitions is left as an exercise.